# iOS: How do I prevent a timer from stopping when swapping screens or when screen sleeps?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, timer

I am writing a basic hh:mm:ss timer app. I have the timer functioning perfectly with start, pause and stop options. My problem is when I swap screens on the app the timer stops and returns to 00:00:00.

Do I need to save it in an array that updates no matter what? Is there a method I can implement or a tutorial available to have the timer continuously count even if I swap screens, go to another app or the screen sleeps?

My code for anyone who wants to implement a timer:

//================= START WORK TIMER =======================//

```
//Work Timer
- (void)updateWorkTimer {

if(working == false) return;

//calculate elapsed time
NSTimeInterval currentTime = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
NSTimeInterval elapsed = workSecondsAlreadyRun + currentTime - startWorkTime;

// extract out the minutes, seconds, and hours of seconds from elapsed time:
int hours = (int)(mins / 60.0);
elapsed -= hours * 60;
int workingMins = (int)(elapsed / 60.0);
elapsed -= workingMins * 60;
int secs = (int) (elapsed);

//update our label using the format of 00:00:00
self.workTimerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02u:%02u:%02u", hours, workingMins, secs];

//call updateTime every 1 second
[self performSelector:@selector(updateWorkTimer) withObject:self afterDelay:1];

}
```

//=================================================================================================================

```
- (IBAction)startWorkButton:(id)sender {

if(working == false) {

    //start timer
    working = true;
    startWorkDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    startWorkTime = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];

    //Set color and title for the button
    [self.startWorkButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    [sender setTitle:@"Pause Work" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self updateWorkTimer];
}
else {
    //pause timer
    workSecondsAlreadyRun += [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:startWorkDate];
    startWorkDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];

    //Set color and title for the button
    UIColor * color = [UIColor colorWithRed:56/255.0f green:171/255.0f blue:10/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
    [self.startWorkButton setBackgroundColor: color ];
    [sender setTitle:@"Resume Work" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    working = false;
}


}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: attach your timer code also..

Comment: @raki I have attached. Does this help regarding a possible solution?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to have the timer running the whole time. Instead, you can simply calculate the time interval (the time that has passed since your app went to background) once your app opens again and then add this to the value of the timer.

For this you need to store the current value of the timer and the current time (`[NSDate date]`) with NSUserDefaults when the app goes to background, and use this data to calculate what value the timer should have once your app starts again. To intercept going to background and foreground you should subscribe to `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification` and `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification`, because `viewDidAppear` and `viewDidDisappear` won't get called.

Comment: The main issue is the swapping of screens. If I move to another screen, I need the timer to continue. The UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification doesn't help so much as because it only displays a notification of an action I am aware of that happened, like leaving the screen (unless I am unaware of other ways of utilising it).

Do I have to store and recall the time when reentering the view after changing views or can I implement a much easier method of simply adding the time interval to the time that was there before leaving?

Comment: Do you know how to use `NSNotificationCenter`? It doesn't display a notification but it gives you the possibility to call a function when certain events happen. I think, storing the current value of the timer and the current time when your viewcontroller disappears (in `viewDidDisappear` and when `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification` is called) and then updating the timer in `viewDidAppear` and `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification`, still is the best method.

Comment: Ok will give that a try. I only knew how to use it for notification rather than implementing other methods.